# Сделать передвижение камеры до определённой точки в C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

я только недавно начал изучать юнити и столкнулся с проблемой.
Хочу чтобы при приближении игрока к объекту и нажатии Е камера плавно передвигалась на определённые координаты, а после некоторого кода уходила на исходную позицию (при диалоге подвигалась, после него отдалялась)
И вот мучаюсь уже несколько дней на приближением... При коде который прикрепил камера медленно уходит в другую сторону.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject playerObject;
    public GameObject triggerObject;
    private vThirdPersonCamera invocerCamera;

    public float smoothSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float minDistance = 7f;

    Vector3 playerPosition;
    Vector3 triggerPosition;
    Vector3 originalCameraPosition;
    Vector3 lastCameraPosition;
    Vector3 stopPosition;

    private bool isMoving = false;
    private float distance;
    private float maxDistance;

    private void Start() {
        invocerCamera = GetComponent<vThirdPersonCamera>();
        originalCameraPosition = transform.position;
        stopPosition = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    }

    private void Update() {
        playerPosition = playerObject.transform.position;
        triggerPosition = triggerObject.transform.position;

        DialogueCameraEnable();
    }

    private void DialogueCameraEnable() {
        playerPosition = playerObject.transform.position;
        triggerPosition = triggerObject.transform.position;
        float playerTriggerDistance = Vector3.Distance(playerPosition, triggerPosition);

        if(playerTriggerDistance <= minDistance) {

            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
                isMoving = !isMoving;
            }

            if(isMoving) {
                Vector3 desiredPosition = isMoving ? playerPosition + new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f) : stopPosition;
                Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(originalCameraPosition, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                invocerCamera.enabled = false;

                if(invocerCamera != null) {
                    invocerCamera.enabled = false;
                }

                if(smoothedPosition != lastCameraPosition) {
                    transform.position = smoothedPosition;
                    lastCameraPosition = smoothedPosition;
                } else {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```